# C#/LINQ Querying a class

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using [Sam Jenkin's Deck of Cards class](http://satalketo.com/2013/04/deck-of-cards-in-c/). I'm trying to query certain cards in a suit. I'm getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I've tried moving things around but I'm not understanding the error. Could someone please help? My code is:

```
var deck = new Deck();

IEnumerable<Deck> deckQuery =
            from myCard in deck.Cards
            where myCard.Suit == Suit.Club
            select myCard.CardNumber;
```

My `Card` class is:

```
public class Card : ICard
{
    public Suit Suit { get; set; }
    public CardNumber CardNumber { get; set; }
}
```

My enumerators are:

```
public enum Suit
{
    Club = 1,
    Diamond = 2,
    Heart = 3,
    Spades = 4,
}

public enum CardNumber
{
    Ace = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
    Six = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine = 9,
    Ten = 10,
    Jack = 11,
    Queen = 12,
    King = 13,
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're selecting a `CardNumber`, but trying to place it into a deck:

```
// This won't work:
// IEnumerable<Deck> deckQuery =
IEnumerable<CardNumber> deckQuery = 
        from myCard in deck.Cards
        where myCard.Suit == Suit.Club
        select myCard.CardNumber;
```

The other option would be to select the card itself:

```
IEnumerable<Card> deckQuery = 
        from myCard in deck.Cards
        where myCard.Suit == Suit.Club
        select myCard;
```

Comment: AHHHH I see. I should have been querying the Card class and not the Deck?

Comment: @Laserbeak43 It all depends on what you want - you can query the deck, but the results need to be "Cards" or "CardNumbers", not decks...  Basically, you're asking for all of the card numbers from the deck where ... - so the result will be an `IEnumerable<CardNumber>`

Answer (score 1):

You are saying

> select myCard.CardNumber;

According to your definition

```
public CardNumber CardNumber { get; set; }
```

It returns a CardNumber

And you are expecting a   `IEnumerable<Deck>` instead of   `IEnumerable<CardNumber>`

If you are trying to get the cards, then just return that

```
select myCard
```

And it Should be `IEnumerable<Card>`

The Deck class is the one that helps you to do some operations with your cards. I think you are looking for returning the cards, you don't want to return Many decks

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is "Selecting `CardNumber` and assigning it to `Deck`"